# Telerik CVE only find key?

Tags: cve

I found that a website is using a version of telerik web UI that may be vulnerable to CVE-2017-9248.

However when I use the python script with command

```
python script.py -k https://www.website.com/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx 48 hex 9
```

It finds the key but is not able to find telerik version and the final link is not generated. Can i still find the working url/parameter?

The exploit is this one: `github.com/bao7uo/RAU_crypto`

It gives me this result:

```
Found key: 81**************************************************************
 
Total web requests: 1395

No valid version found
```

Once the script finds the telerik version in use should generate the full URL.

Real question here is: if I found the key, how can I encrypt the key to get the full base64 valid token?

Comment: "the python script" -- which script?

Comment: @schroeder,

This one: https://github.com/bao7uo/RAU_crypto

It gives me this result:

Found key: 81**************************************************************
Total web requests: 1395
No valid version found

Once the script finds the telerik version in use should generate the full url.

Real question here is: if i found the key, how can i encrypt the key to get the full base64 valid token?

Comment: Please edit your  question with these new details instead of adding them all in comments